# Why does the Quran not mention a punishment for the people of 'Isa pbuh?

Tags: quran, tafseer, punishment, prophet-isa

When we read the Qur'an we find verses addressing or referring to the (wrongdoers among the) people of almost all prophets and messengers and their punishment see for example:

- > Has there not reached them the news of those before them - the people of **Noah** and [the tribes of] **'Aad** and **Thamud** and the people of **Abraham** and the companions of **Madyan** and the towns overturned? Their messengers came to them with clear proofs. And Allah would never have wronged them, but they were wronging themselves. ([9:70](https://legacy.quran.com/9/70))
- > And if they deny you, [O Muhammad] - so, before them, did the people of **Noah** and **'Aad** and **Thamud** deny [their prophets], (42)
  >   And the people of **Abraham** and the people of **Lo**t (43)
  >   And the inhabitants of **Madyan**. And **Moses** was denied, so I prolonged enjoyment for the disbelievers; then I seized them, and how [terrible] was My reproach. ([22:42-44](https://legacy.quran.com/22/42-44))

But I couldn't find similar references for the people of 'Isa () (Jesus) and wonder if this actually is the case and if so is there an explanation why a punishment for them is not mentioned, even if they have wronged him ()?

Comment: Afaik there is no historical record of any torment from God on the Romans after they 'tried to crucify' Jesus. Looking forward to the answers this question receives to increase my knowledge.

Comment: Technically the Romans were only a tool used by the Bani Israel. Jesus was sent to them ([61:6](https://quran.com/61/6)). They were the ones who disbelieved in him, plotted against him, accused him, brought him to trial and insisted that he be killed and they are the ones held responsible for it in the Quran ([5:110](http://quran.com/5/110), [4:157](http://quran.com/4/157))

Answer (score 2):

There is a view that no Heavenly annihilation came after the revelation of the Torah.

> ولقد آتينا موسى الكتاب من بعد ما أهلكنا القرون الأولى
>
> And We gave Moses the Scripture, after We had destroyed the former generations
>
> <sup>— [Quran 28:43](http://quran.com/28/43)</sup>

> عن أبي سعيد الخدري رضي الله عنه عن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: ما أهلك الله قوما، ولا قرنا، ولا أمة، ولا أهل قرية منذ أنزل التوراة على وجه الأرض بعذاب من السماء غير أهل القرية التي مسخت قردة ألم تر إلى قوله تعالى: {ولقد آتينا موسى الكتاب من بعد ما أهلكنا القرون الأولى بصائر للناس وهدى ورحمة لعلهم يتذكرون} [القصص: 43] صحيح على شرط الشيخين ولم يخرجاه
>
> Abu Sa‘id al-Khudri said: The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said:
>
> Allah has not destroyed any nation, people, ummah or city, since He sent the Torah to the face of the earth, by heavenly punishment; except the people of city who were transformed (for breaking the Sabbath). Do you not see His saying: *And We gave Moses the Scripture, after We had destroyed the former generations, as enlightenment for the people and guidance and mercy that they might be reminded.* [Al-Qasas : 43]
>
> <sup>— [Mustadrak al-Hakim - كتاب التفسير -  تفسير سورة القصص 3534](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/3676#p1)</sup>

Secondly, the people of Isa عليه السلام were the Bani Israel. Shortly after his ascent came the Roman-Jewish war and the [Siege of Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)), where the entire populace was killed and enslaved and the second Temple was destroyed.

> فإذا جاء وعد الآخرة ليسوءوا وجوهكم وليدخلوا المسجد كما دخلوه أول مرة وليتبروا ما علوا تتبيرا
>
> Then when the final promise came, [We sent your enemies] to sadden your faces and to enter the temple [in Jerusalem], as they entered it the first time, and to destroy what they had taken over with [total] destruction.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:7](http://quran.com/17/7)</sup>

Comment: Maybe losing Allah's favour and getting his curse was their punishment.

Answer (score 0):

In surah al Imran is says:

(And remember) when Allah said: O Jesus! Lo! I am gathering thee and causing thee to ascend unto Me, and am cleansing thee of those who disbelieve and am setting those who follow thee above those who disbelieve until the Day of Resurrection. Then unto Me ye will (all) return, and I shall judge between you as to that wherein ye used to differ. (3:55) As for those who disbelieve I shall chastise them with a heavy chastisement in the world and the Hereafter; and they will have no helpers. (3:56) And as for those who believe and do good works, He will pay them their wages in full. Allah loveth not wrong-doers. (3:57)

This surah clearly states that Allah will set those who believe in Jesus above those that don't believe in him and that he will punish those who disbelieve in Jesus in the world and the hereafter.